# SQL: percantage change for all possible combinations

Tags: sql, lag, cube

I started to learn SQL and have the following tables (they include way more data but only those seem necessary to the problem).

ITEM:

```
item_keys   deparment_desc
----------------------------
10001       Womens Clothing  
10002       Womens Clothing  
10003       Sporting Goods
```

SALES:

```
cur_trn_date  item_key  store_key  tot_sls_qty
----------------------------------------------
1999-12-01    10001     1          8346.17  
1999-12-01    10001     2          235.40 
.  
.  
.  
2001-12-31    2001-12-31  10       1108.33
```

STORE:

```
store_key   type_key   type_desc
--------------------------------
1           1          Super Malls  
2           2          Strip Malls  
3           3          Retail Only  
.  
.  
.  
10          1           Super Malls
```

(I'm sorry if that's not really looking really structured, I couldn't find a way to create tables at StackOverflow)

What I would like to get, are the total sales for each year as well as the percentage change to last year. All that for all possible combinations of department_desc and type_desc. I tried it with the following code but there seems to be a problem with the CUBE and maybe the LAG function.
They are an unexpected token.

```
SELECT YEAR(s.cur_trn_date) AS year, SUM(s.tot_sls_qty) AS sales,
(SUM(s.tot_sls_qty) - LAG(SUM(s.tot_sls_qty)) / SUM(s.tot_sls_qty)) AS difference
FROM sales s, item i, store st
GROUP BY YEAR(s.cur_trn_date)
CUBE(i.departmend_desc, st.type_desc)
WHERE s.item_key = i.item_key
AND s.store_key = st.store_key
```

If anybody could help out or give me a clue on what the issue could be, that would be great.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit JOIN syntax. Easier to write (**without errors**), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: `WHERE`  comes before `GROUP BY`.

Comment: "*I couldn't find a way to create tables at StackOverflow*" - see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 0):

From what you describe, the query should be:

```
SELECT YEAR(s.cur_trn_date) AS year,
       SUM(s.tot_sls_qty) AS sales,
       (SUM(s.tot_sls_qty) - LAG(SUM(s.tot_sls_qty)) / 
        SUM(s.tot_sls_qty)
       ) AS difference
FROM sales s JOIN
     item i
     ON s.item_key = i.item_key JOIN
     store st
     ON s.store_key = st.store_key
GROUP BY GROUPING_SETS ( (YEAR(s.cur_trn_date)),
                         (YEAR(s.cur_trn_date), i.departmend_desc, st.type_desc),
                         (YEAR(s.cur_trn_date), i.departmend_desc),
                         (YEAR(s.cur_trn_date), st.type_desc)
                       );
```

I'm not sure if having a syntax that will actually run will fix your problem.  (I prefer `grouping sets` over `cube` because I like to be explicit about the results being produced.)